# how to solve can't export database in phpmyadmin?

Tags: xampp

when I want to export an existing database in phpmyadmin, I have a problem, namely the database cannot be exported with a failded-network error description. I've tried changing the network but the result is still the same. how to solve can't export database in phpmyadmin?

Comment: in all honesty: by not using phpmyadmin. There's very little reason to use that to export a database – you can do the same in basic SQL / MariaDB instructions yourself. You have a tunnel to your server anyways (right? You're **not** exposing phpmyadmin to the internet, **right**? That's a very bad idea, because it circumvents source IP filtering), so make a tunnel to your MariaDB port, connect to the database using any local tool you like and make your dump.

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty: by not using phpmyadmin.

There's very little reason to use that to export a database – you can do the same in basic SQL / MariaDB instructions yourself. You have a tunnel to your server anyways¹, so make a tunnel to your MariaDB port, connect to the database using any local tool you like and make your database dump.

---

¹  Right? You're **not** exposing phpmyadmin to the internet, **right**? That's a very bad idea, because it circumvents source IP filtering, and thus exposes your SQL server to brute force password attacks, not to mention the numerous security holes that phpmyadmin has had over the past.